# Ajax POST never works, status 405

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

```
$.ajax({

    url: "http://www.voyga.top/shan/form.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: "feedback=" + feedback,

    success: function(response) {

        // do something...

    }

});
```

this is my javascript file. I'm not using jquery, I'm using my own ajax function:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open(options.method, options.url, true);
xhr.send(options.data);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (xhr.readyState === 4 &&
        xhr.status === 200) {

        options.success(xhr.responseText);

    }

};
```

my php code:

```
<?php

    $feedback = $_POST["feedback"];

    echo $feedback;

    ?>
```

for the same url, "GET" works fine but "POST" keep showing status 405 not allowed (even when posting local files). What's the problem? Is it about my code?

Comment: are you sure options.data is a URL-encoded text string? that would be the format: encodeURIComponent(variable1.name)+"=".encodeURIComponent(variable1.value)+"&"+encodeURIComponent(variable2.name)+"="+encodeURIComponent(variable2.value)    and so on~

Answer (score 0):

This is because, the server you are requesting using POST is not reading data from the POST Super Global variable.

The server wants a client to send data using GET Method and the API on that server, programmed to read GET Super Global variable.

**Conclusion:** This is not an issue,

1. You have to use GET method if the API is third party (means you do not have access to API code).
2. If you have access to code of server then check it properly and take an appropriate action to read POST Super Global variable.

Hope this will helps you to understand what is happening.

Comment: uhhh, i GUESS you are talking about how PHP would interpret the http request (_POST and _GET superglobal variables where PHP would put the data), but OP made no mention of PHP. but you're probably right, the data is sent in the URL GET data, not as part of the POST data, and his server code - whatever language its in - is only reading the GET data, not the POST data (if any)

Comment: But the php file I'm requesting is using _POST variable? And if I use GET it returns me the source code of the php file?

Comment: My goal is to send data to the php file and store it to the database.

Comment: Give it a try with _REQUEST variable

Comment: @JitendraKhatri I think this has nothing todo with the php file, I cannot successfully "POST" anything, all status 405

Comment: This status is actually returned by Server when "Method Not Allowed" error rises. Try to dump data with print_r($_REQUEST) and share your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved.
It is because my php file is hosted by Github Pages which doesn't support php and POST method... I changed the host and it works. Thanks for you guys' help.

Comment: I think I have the same problem and you've mentioned changing the host did the trick for you, which vendor did you end up hosting it in?